# I have several arrays of text values and I want to select one of the arrays to use as an HTML datalist

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy, datalist

I have several arrays of text values and I want to use one of them to populate an HTML datalist based on the user's selection of the value in another datalist. I don't know how to code this.

Here is my code but it isn't complete. See the ???? and I may need some additional code. Would it be best practice to keep the map arrays in the HTML or put them in one or more files (js or text). If they should be in files, I'm not sure how to reference them.

This works if I hard code to use map1 or map2 instead of mapArray.

```
<script>
    var str=''; // variable to store the options
    var mapName = map; //will be text "Map 1" or "Map 2" up to "Map 30"
    var map1 = new Array("Caitlin", "Roadrunner", "More Values");
    var map2 = new Array("Ceedee #1, Ceedee#2"); // up to 30 values
    var mapArray[] = ????? //I want to copy the array for Map 1 or Map 2..
    for (var i=0; i < mapArray.length;++i) {
    str += '<option value="'+mapArray[i]+'" />'; // Storing options in      
    // variable
    }
    var my_list=document.getElementById("theList");
    my_list.innerHTML = str;
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a use for the [spread operator `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals)

```
var map1 = new Array("Caitlin", "Roadrunner", "More Values");
var map2 = new Array("Ceedee #1, Ceedee#2");
var mapArray = [...map1, ...map2]; 
// map1 is now ["Caitlin", "Roadrunner", "More Values", "Ceedee #1, Ceedee#2"]
```

Comment: This will merge the two groups of options, does not look like OP would want this

Comment: Whoops, my mistake then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the push array function to store a new element at the end of an array.

So if you wanted to create an array of your arrays, you could do:

```
var mapArray = new Array();
var map1 = new Array("Caitlin", "Roadrunner", "More Values");
mapArray.push(map1);
var map2 = new Array("Ceedee #1, Ceedee#2");
mapArray.push(map2);
```

This would result in the value `mapArray` being equal to `[ map1, map2 ]`.

You would need to modify your `for` loop, because this is a 2D array.

So it might look something like:

```
// choice variable is the chosen input from user
for (var i=0; i < mapArray[choice].length; ++i) {
    str += '<option value="'+mapArray[choice][i]+'" />';
}
```

As for your other questions, they are mostly opinion-based. I recommend that you get your desired functionality working and then expanding from there to see if you can make the code cleaner.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I only want to populate the datalist with the map1 values if the user has selected Map 1 from the prior datalist choice on the form. If the user selected Map 2, then I only want to populate the datalist with the map2 values. mapArray should only contain Caitlin, Roadrunner, and More Values or it should only contain Ceedee #1 and Ceedee#2.

Answer (score 0):

No need to copy the arrays, just store all of your available options in an object and access the array you would like by index.

Also, you could populate the `<select/>` element without building string. By using [`Option()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) your code would be far less prone to unescaped character issues.

```js
const selectedMap = 'map1';
const maps = {
  'map1': ["Caitlin", "Roadrunner", "More Values"],
  'map2': ["Ceedee #1, Ceedee#2"]
};

let theList = document.getElementById("theList");
theList.options = []; // Empty out all previous options in the <select/> (if any)
maps[selectedMap].forEach((val, index) => {
  theList[index] = new Option(val, val); 
});
```

```html
<select id='theList'></select>
```